# How to make google datastore persistent in java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, groovy, google-cloud-datastore

It's very slow to test datastore api in cloud in my country, I hope a way to test datastore code in local. so I found following code:

```
package ro.gae

import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper

/**
 * Created by roroco on 8/23/15.
 */
trait LcDatastore {
    LocalServiceTestHelper h = new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());

    def iiLcDs() {
        h.setUp()
    }

    def closeLcDs() {
        h.tearDown()
    }
}
```

But above code only save records in memory, and these records will disappear after code finish. I hope a way to save records in my disk to simplify my code

**update**
I hope the way don't need to start dev_server since dev_server need a long startup in java

Comment: what's the reason to keep test data after test is finished? by "long startup" what you mean? how long?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Since I hope test real data in local, the real data is large, and if it disappear after test, I must load this large data before each test, it's too slow

Comment: are you talking about functional/integration testing? or unit testing?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I prefer it can be used in production and test environment, and it don't need to run dev_server

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you want. for prod you use google hosted db; for dev and integration testing you use local db kept between runs; for unit testing in memory ephemeral db

Answer (score 1):

did you try something like this?

```
public class MyTestClass {
    LocalServiceTestHelper localServiceTestHelper;

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass(){
        LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig localDatastoreServiceTestConfig = new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig();
        localDatastoreServiceTestConfig.setBackingStoreLocation("storagefilelocation");
        localDatastoreServiceTestConfig.setNoStorage(false);

        localServiceTestHelper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(localDatastoreServiceTestConfig);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething(){

    }
}
```

edit: By the way, I aggree with @Igor Artamonov that this is very likely a bad idea. It should work though. I can also think of a few things that this could help with; like importing huge datasets into the dev local storage by running a unit test (or any external application).